# How do you install a slide lock when the door frame isn't level with the door?

Tags: lock

I need to lock a door without a keyhole from the inside and got recommended to use something like this:

[image]

However, my door frame isn't level with the door

[image]

If I would just mount it there, the slider would probably just slide over the holding thing. How would I mount it there?

Comment: why on earth is your door that far out of plane with your jamb?

Comment: @paperstreet:  This is a common door installation in many regions.  I specifically remember seeing that in many residences and hotels in Netherlands, Germany, Denmark, Norway, Sweden, etc.

Comment: Well if doors are commonly installed that way in those areas odds are there is hardware designed to work in that situation. Never fabricate when you can buy something off the shelf.

Comment: @wallyk any idea why they install the doors that way?

Comment: @paperstreet:  Alas, I never asked, or if I did, the answer was along the lines of "because that is how they are made."  It does make the latch more secure so you can't open it with a credit card or knife, and no light passes around the top and sides so it does make hotel hallways subtly more private.  It also reduce smoke and sound traveling through the door.

Comment: Oh so the door is actually rabbeted out onto the jamb? I could see the benefits of that design.

Answer (score 3):

depending on how much you want to work with this and who you're trying to keep out, you could just put several washers behind each hole on the jamb side.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution, of course, would be to fix the door frame, but this would take a lot of work.

It appears that the door jamb is metal, and slightly wider than the part of the lock that accepts the slide? If so, find a piece of filler material (perhaps a layer or two of metal bar stock/billets), that will thicken the door jamb to meet the door. Use some longer sheet metal screws to attach the part to the door jamb. Be sure to drill holes in the filler material so that the screws easily go through the metal stock, so that they can dig into the door jamb itself.

Note that you may need to use fairly large screws to fully secure the lock. If smaller screws are used, one could easily kick open the door as the heads off the screws will easily pop off given reasonable force.